# "Faulting module name: clr.dll" error message when you run a Microsoft .NET Framework 4-based application

Tags: .net

I have a application which was working fine until i move on to Dot net framework 4. Now whenever i install and open my appication it crashes with the below error msg.

```
 Problem signature:
 Problem Event Name:    APPCRASH
 Application Name:  Myapplication.exe
 Application Version:   8.0.18428.531
 Application Timestamp: 50dc3ecf
 Fault Module Name: clr.dll
 Fault Module Version:  4.0.30319.1
 Fault Module Timestamp:    4ba21eeb
 Exception Code:    c00000fd
 Exception Offset:  000000000010791f
 OS Version:    6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
 Locale ID: 1033
 Additional Information 1:  4598
 Additional Information 2:  45986a8b8021cca3bd025450731a9c6a
 Additional Information 3:  e90e
 Additional Information 4:  e90e0a2cf591d6675172685f07f0ec36
```

I have done some googling and find out that we are not the only one who is facing this  problem. then i found this link 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2640103
which tells the problem of Dot net framework 4 and suggesting to install a hotfix that resolves this problem . Problem is? i couldn't figure out where to get the hotfix that they are talking about.

someone suggest this link for the hotfix   https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=29638

i downloaded and installed it but still the same error occurs.Am i installing the     right hotfix .Please guide me .

Comment: You crashed with this site's name.  The 99% odds for a stack overflow is a bug in your code.  Avoid assuming it has anything to do with the CLR, it is merely the one that pulled the plug, SOE is a fatal exception that instantly terminates your app.

Comment: As @Hans-Passant mentions, Exception Code c00000fd is a Win32 Exception, Stack overflow, that suggest that your code has the fault, typically an infinite recursive call.

Answer (score 2):

I am too experiencing this issue with .NET 4.0 CLR.DLL (under XP only). The [hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2640103) mentioned in the OP's question has indeed helped. Here's how to obtain it:

http://support.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=2640103&kbln=en-us

(Can be applied to any hotfix, as described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mmcintyr/archive/2008/09/02/how-can-you-download-a-hotfix-without-contacting-microsoft.aspx)).

**[UPDATE]** This hotfix was superseded by http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2889629 (at the time of posting this).